# How to pass data in arrow function on clicking a div, without passing as parameter and without showing value in dom?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

I want to share the data of below div when it is clicked, data is an info. but I don't want to show that info. on dom. I mean I don't want it to appear in the div when someone do inspect element. But I also not want to pass it as arrow function like this: `(value) => this.sharedValue(value)`

```
<div onClick={this.sharedValue} class="cursor-pointer">ALTICOR INC</div>
```

So I want to know is there any way to share information to a function using events and its properties in react or javascript without showing information on dom or without passing it as arrow function parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-dom:

See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom

And use it like this

```
sharedValue() {
    const domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    alert(domNode.innerText);
  }
```